# Track visits every time a hidden div is shown

Tags: php, jquery, html, hidden, user-tracking

I have a contact form that uses jquery to display a message above the form once it is submitted. It basically shows error messages and successful messages upon validating the info.

My question: I want to be able to track how many times the successful message was loaded. The message area is just a div

```
<div id="message"></div>
```

The validation code is done in php. How can I keep track of how many visitors successfully submitted the form?  I'm trying to avoid adding database post functions as I am not good at that nor really need that function.

Comment: Can you load some single-pixel images and let the server do the counting?

Answer (score 2):

You will need database post functions if you want to record that.

- Edit:

If you need to store something about the use of your page it can be done in a couple of ways.
You could create an ajax call that increments a counter in a database this would need some server side code or..
you could embed a 3rd party tracking service  tool like google analytics, or one of many others, which would basically be doing the ajax call to their servers, then you can access the data.. or
another way is mentioned below in parsing the web server logs, only simple if you have access to server log parsing tools.

Comment: Elaborate a bit more as to why the OP needs a database.

Comment: I think 3rd party analytics or an AJAX POST to server method would be much easier to create and maintain than parsing web logs. With logs you'd have to parse and process logs from each server, plus handle log rotation.

Comment: @GiscardBiamby parsing server logs is trivial.  Log rotation is automatic if you set it up properly in the server config file properly. There are enough tools for parsing logs out there that it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Giscard Yes but he is *trying to avoid adding database post functions as I am not good at that nor really need that function*.

Comment: Yes, it's trivial, but so is adding an AJAX call to track the actions. Between the two I would find a server post method easier. Depends on what you're more comfortable with I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Web servers have access logs.  Parse them and you should get the information you ned.

Answer (score 1):

**Load a single-pixel white image** from your server and then let the server do the counting for you.

```
<div id="message"><img src="http://www.example.com/pix.png" /></div>
```

There are tools that analyze the logs of your web server and extract the number of requests of a certain file, like [awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but what I've understood is that you don't want want to use database to save your track records. If so then you can create a log file and just write to that file after each successful submission. May be some code will help me to answer it more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely going to need a way to increment a counter and that counter *has* to be persistent. PHP counters only exist while PHP is executing; all variables are cleared when the web server is finished responding to a request.

That means, you'll either need to increment the counter in a database, or in a text file.

When you show the success div with jquery, add the following:

```
  $('#message').show();
  //add from here
  var url = "http://yoursite.com/successcounter.php";
  $.post(url, {}, function(r){
    console.log(r);
  }); 
  //to here
```

Then on your server, have successcounter.php increment the success counter in a database, or a textfile.

[Tizag's File Write Tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php) or [PHP.net's MySQL documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php).